# Facebook open graph tag errors (geopoint)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, geopoints

The following meta tags produce the linter warning below. I read on a blog or two that facebook no longer uses these tags, but given their interface, I have a hard time believing it. Does anyone see any problems?

```
  <meta property="og:latitude" content="27.41076"> 
  <meta property="og:longitude" content="-82.65850"> 
  <meta property="og:street-address" content="5441 Gulf of Mexico Drive"> 
  <meta property="og:locality" content="Longboat Key"> 
  <meta property="og:region" content="FL"> 
  <meta property="og:postal-code" content="34228"> 
  <meta property="og:country-name" content="USA"> 
  <meta property="og:locale" content="en_us" />
```

---

[image]

---

**Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:latitude'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:longitude'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:street-address'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:locality'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:region'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:postal-code'.

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'og:country-name'.

Answer (score 2):

The meta tags should start with your namespace e.g.

```
<meta property="place:location:latitude" content="45.50251415561716" /> 
<meta property="place:location:longitude" content="-73.5713430027785" /> 
<meta property="place:location:altitude" content="42" />
```

See more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/complextypes/#geopoint

See it in action at http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/geopoint.html

*Warning*: there is currently a bug with the debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/432088663509632

Comment: Hrm. Should I be adding these properties in the admin console? As is, the post is completing successfully, but there is no indication that the lat / long are being used for anything (I was hoping for a generated map).

Comment: @Matrym I would show how it looks but the current bug is messing up things

Comment: any chance you could screenshot the admin console view?

Comment: But actually, why don't i get even GeoPoint option.

Comment: @sathiamoorthy you may have to be more descriptive of your problem

Comment: Instead of property="yourapp:location:latitude" it should be property="place:location:latitude"

Comment: @MichałCzapko it used to be namespace at one point, fixed now